# Array that include any substring from another array?

Tags: node.js

I have 2 arrays of the following format:

```
array1 = ['cat', 'man', 'new']
array2 = ['catch', 'jim', 'manners', 'renew', 'newcomer']
```

I am trying to find an array that contains items of array 2 if any of the strings in array 1 are contained in the string of array 2. In this case the output would be:
`['catch', 'manners', 'renew', 'newcomer']`
I know that I could to this with a forloop but am curious if there is a simpler 1 line solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a regular expression using alternation:

```js
const array1 = ['cat', 'man', 'new'];
const array2 = ['catch', 'jim', 'manners', 'renew', 'newcomer'];

const result = array2.filter(v => RegExp(array1.join('|')).test(v));

console.log(result);
```

Notes:

- You have to be careful when the strings include special characters, they will need to be escaped.
- From a performance perspective, it's better to build the `RegExp` once instead of creating it inside the `filter()` callback.

Answer (score 0):

With [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) this can be done in one line:

```js
let array1 = ['cat', 'man', 'new'];
let array2 = ['catch', 'jim', 'manners', 'renew', 'newcomer'];

let ans = array2.filter(x => array1.some(a => x.includes(a)));

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
array1 = ['cat', 'man', 'new']
array2 = ['catch', 'jim', 'manners', 'renew', 'newcomer']

const result = array2.filter(word => array1.some(phrase => word.includes(phrase)))
console.log(result)
```

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)